# python one variable contains lists. how to combine into a list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I scrape data from website and I used a variable to contain all lists of data.

i.e.

```
x = [a,d,d,d] [a,f,f,f] [a,f,g,r]
```

---

How can I put them into one list like following:

```
x = [[a,d,d,d],[a,f,f,f],[a,f,g,r]]
```

---

The code I used:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = "http://www.dicj.gov.mo/web/en/information/DadosEstat_mensal/2018/report_en.xml?id=5"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'xml')

my_data = soup.find_all('RECORD')[0:]
for tds in my_data:
   x = [i.get_text() for i in tds.find_all('DATA')]
   print(x)
```

Comment: By the way, in your code, the `[0:]` in `my_data = soup.find_all('RECORD')[0:]` does not serve any purpose so you can remove it. It essentially means select all list elements from the zero-th index to the end of the list.

Comment: @AbhinavSood Thanks for reminder!

Comment: @TimCastelijns I read that question before but I do not understand at that time. Since I am new in here, should I delete this question if it is dup?

Comment: @FramerB You are under no obligation to delete your question, especially if you didn't find the linked duplicate useful. If enough other people vote that it is a duplicate, it will be automatically marked as one.

Comment: @khelwood Got it !  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a new `x` each time through your `for` loop. You can append each `x` to a list.

```
xs = []
for tds in my_data:
    x = [i.get_text() for i in tds.find_all('DATA')]
    print(x)
    xs.append(x)
```

Or you can use a list comprehension and do it all in one line.

```
xs = [[i.get_text() for i in tds.find_all('DATA')] for tds in my_data]
```

Comment: surely there is a dupe for this

Comment: For the first suggestion, when I try to write : print(xs.append(x)) , the output is all 'NONE'

But the second one works!

Comment: They both work. They produce the same final list `xs`. There's no point trying to print `xs.append(x)` since `list.append` always returns None.